# clion autocomplete keeps processing forever

Tags: autocomplete, intellisense, clion

I am using clion latest version 2020.2

```
Build #CL-202.6397.106, built on July 28, 2020
```

Autocomplete suddenly stopped working even though clion can build and complie my code just fine.

To make sure the issue is not project dependent, I started a new project. However, the problem still presists. As you can see in the attached image below. Whenever I explicity press `(ctrl+space)` I get this empty suggestion dropdown and the icon keeps rotating forever. (**Note:** If I don't press ctrl+space, the dropdown menu never shows up)

I made sure that *PowerSaveMode is disabled.*

I also tried *File->Invalidate Cache/Restart->Invalidate and Restart*

Did anyone face a similar issue? Any suggestions to what could be the cause of this problem?

[image: error sample]

**Additonal information**

gcc version: `gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.5-4ubuntu8) 4.8.5`

g++ version: `g++ (Ubuntu 4.8.5-4ubuntu8) 4.8.5`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am posting this answer in case someone comes across this issue in the future.

The issue was definitly caused by the new update to clion. So I installed an older version. There is a tool named "JetBrains Toolbox" which is very convient when it comes managing multiple versions of any JetBrains software (clion in my case).

An additional note, if you want to run clion (or any other solution) as a superuser do not do that through the JetBrains toolbox. The toolbox will have the installtion location for each installed version, use it to run as a superuser from the terminal.